# Rust/VSCode Debugging Does not Display Peripheral Registers

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, stm32, stm32h743

I am failing at getting the peripheral registers to show up on the vscode debugging screen.

Using a Nucleo 144 board, I downloaded the appropriate `STM32H743.svd` file and put in the path in launch.json as "svdFile": "${workspaceRoot}/STM32H743.svd" like instructed at [cortex-m quickstart guide](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cortex-m-quickstart/blob/master/.vscode/README.md).

Everything else about the debugging works alright except this. There is no obvious error message anywhere. I am using the `rust-analyzer` and `Cortex-Debug` extensions.

This is what i see in the VScode debugging tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have come across [this discussion](https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/issues/565), suggesting that one should use the pre-release version of the Cortex-Debug extension for now. This has indeed fixed the issue for me.